# How to represent a binary field in programming language?

Tags: binary

I am working on my project of Elliptic Curve Cryptography which requires programming on binary fields. It includes basic operations like addition, multiplication, inversion etc w.r.t. an irreducible binary polynomial.

I am searching for a way by which these binary polynomials can be stored in a program. I am working on C and C++ programming language (with *gmp* library) so the first thought came to my mind was to use structures and bit-fields. But they are not dynamic and can't hold arbitrarily long polynomials. Using C++ Vector STL is possible but it won't be efficient, as it stores a single bit in a single word of $8$ or more bits.

Is there any way of representation which is efficient?

Comment: It sounds like your question is more about finding appropriate data structures to support operations on bit fields containing up to a few hundred bits. This makes the question off-topic on MSE in my opinion. But I wait for other opinions before I close. Also because I share your pain. This was one of the reasons I was discouraged from studying the C language 25 years ago. What's the point of having bit fields, if you cannot define a length longer than 16 (or 32 or whatever) :-)

Comment: Undoubtedly you know this, but in some cases it is more efficient to use a normal basis presentation of a large finite field of characteristic two. Squaring is then a cyclic shift, and, if you are lucky, multiplication is fast, because the array defining products of basis elements is very sparse.

Comment: Other opinions came. Initiating migration.

Answer (score 1):

I would use either `std::vector<unsigned char>` or `std::array<unsigned char, SIZE>`. Cryptographic primitives are typically of a fixed length, so they may be easily stored using `std::array`. However if you need values of varying length I would recommend `std::vector`. Using `unsigned char` instead of `char` simplifies computations.

Using `std::vector<bool>` does not use one byte per data bit as it is specialized to store 8 bits in a single byte. That being said however, it would be quite slow to read and write each bit individually, so I would not recommend it for your purposes.